# Error webservice when publishing infopath 2010 form to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services

I am referring to the below link to publish infopath form

[guide to publishing infopath forms as admin approved form templates](http://www.manojn.com/2013/01/guide-to-publishing-infopath-forms-as-admin-approved-form-templates)

add my infopath form in trusted form templates in CA :

[image: sharepoint trusted form templates]

then add my connections to manage data connection files :

[image: manage data connections]

then test my form in info path and worked properly

but when it opened by InfoPath services in web browser this error occurred:

[image: error-on-form-call-web-services]

When I create one infopath form, I see this error:

> A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action
>   would violate cross-domain restrictions.

If this form template is published to a SharePoint document library, cross-domain access for user form templates must be enabled under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration, and the data connection settings must be stored in a UDC file in a data connection library in the same site collection.

If this is an administrator-approved form template, the security level of the form must be set to full trust, or the data connection settings must be stored in a UDC file by using the Manage data connection files option under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration.

> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.  Log
>   ID:6932
>
> Correlation ID:e692623b-fd86-4ba1-89a7-305fbda02762

I am using user account having administrator privilege.

Comment: Could you please share what error you have come across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you forget steps in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2012/08/17/want-to-call-sharepoint-2010-web-services-within-browser-based-infopath-2010-forms.aspx) :

please prepare a checklist and tik step by step and compare with your way

1. Update the data connection web service URL to call the new Web App URL configured with Classic Authentication
2. Create a data connection library in a given site collection
3. The data connection must be converted to file of type UDCX
4. Download the UDCX from the data connection library and edit with notepad
5. The form must be full trusted and published locally
6. The form template and data connection file are uploaded to SharePoint Central Administrator
7. Adjust configuration settings within Central Admin InfoPath Forms Services
8. Activate the form to a Site Collection hosted by a Claims Based Web Application
9. Test to ensure the form works without error

make sure that you use from that template in trusted infopath templates in CA

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I was at the wrong address to the administrator-approved.I enter the location address in our system, not the address of the SharePoint site & I publish the form stored in our system in Central Admin.But I found new error. During the form process. But first, an error occurs.

An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.
An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 
Log ID:5566
Correlation ID:37bf3ad0-1c61-4c3d-9311-ec4983b1a800

Have an idea??!